# Unity Collision doesn't work as expected if one is inside a Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, collider

I am using Unity 2019.4.17f1 and I have two objects with colliders and I want to detect if one of them collides with the other, so OnCollisionEnter should be called on both objects (although I really only care if it is called on the other cube because the first one will just be a controller so that the second collider does something once it detects that the controller collides with it). To do the test I have this scene with three cubes:

[image]

And a component that is included in the three cubes with the next code:

```
public string text;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision made: " + text);
}
```

Each of them has a text variable with the name of the colour they have so when they collides they will show the text with the colour that is colliding, there are also only two rigidbody there, one inside Blue Cube and other inside Rb GameObject, both of them has no gravity.

But as you can see in the previous picture only Blue and Red debug text are shown, so when Blue is colliding with Green only Blue reacts and if Blue collides with Red both Blue and Red are shown. Why it reacts different if the object is child of a rigidbody and what can I do to make that Green also reacts to the collision?

**EDIT:**

I also test if the Red cube have a Rigidbody on it and it works as expected (Blue and Red messages appears) so I don't understand why Green doesn't work too.

**EDIT2:**

This is the Rb GameObject:

[image]

And the Green GameObject:

[image]

Comment: Can you show / tell us whats inside the rb gameobject and whats inside the green cube gameobject?

Comment: @DanielM I added pictures of the Rb and Green GameObjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Unity colliders documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

> Compound colliders approximate the shape of a GameObject while keeping a low processor overhead. To get further flexibility, you can add additional colliders on child GameObjects. For instance, you can rotate boxes relative to the local axes of the parent GameObject. When you create a compound collider like this, **you should only use one Rigidbody component, placed on the root GameObject in the hierarchy**.

Make sure that your `DetectCollider` script and `RigidBody` component are attached to the root GameObject which in this case is Rb. Collision events get passed from colliders to attached or parent RigidBody so your CollisionScripts should be attached accordingly. Also make sure that Green GameObject doesn't have Rigidbody attached so the events get passed to parent Rigidbody in Rb instead.

In this case you have `DetectCollision` attached to child Green gameobject but `RigidBody` attached to Rb which means Collision Events get passed to Rb GameObject and not to Green gameobject.